# How to convert greek text to unicode using matching input method?

Tags: latex, replace, unicode, elisp-macros, input-method

Good evening,

I have a large TeX-file with Greek inclusions in traditional babel way: `\textgreek{sunj'hkh|}`.  I would like to convert it to unicode for further work. Emacs has greek-babel input method, so just typing these keys with input method toggled would do the job.  But can I somehow use it with the matched substrings to process the whole buffer?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question well, but perhaps a small utility I wrote could help you -  https://github.com/aadcg/emacs-yeis.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion.  As far as I can see, it relies on robin package and its own input methods.  There is robin-greek method among them, but it differs from greek-babel which is my case. Can robin make use of greek-babel?

Comment: It would be trivial to add a new input method. If you need help, fire up an issue on github.

Comment: Yeah! that was trivial. Thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure. I'm sure you'll find lots of issues with this small utility. Feel free to report those, and to send a PR/patch to add this new input method you defined.